# Alternatives for panning and zooming

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming

I have a view with many subviews (representing mathematical objects -- think of a system of equations, with each term in each equation a separate control). I want to be able to zoom in and out of the view, and to pan around it. But I *don't* want to use `UIScrollView`, at least not the traditional way, because the controls in the view use a lot of the same gestures -- swipes, pinches, etc.

One alternative is to use `UIScrollView` but to "lock" the view so it doesn't zoom or pan, allowing the controls to receive those gestures, and then to zoom and pan using buttons -- sort of like the controls on Mapquest (online). But this feels very "discrete" (not continuous and smooth) and old-fashioned.

Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using standard UI elements like scroll bars and buttons to manipulate the main view you can use a custom floating navigation control.  Make a small rect in one corner of the view that always remains there and retains its size regardless of the zoom or pan values of the main view.  The user can use standard gestures in there to zoom and pan the main view.
The trick is to make it intuitive so that it's obvious to the user that this is how the view is used.  Displaying a shrunken down snapshot of the overall view within the rect is one technique.

By the way, I'm not sure what you mean when you say that using standard controls isn't continuous and smooth.  Why not?  You should be able to get the same level of interactivity that you get with gestures.

Comment: This is a nice idea. It might be hard to make it intuitive, as you said. About "not smooth," I just meant that the typical Mapquest-type control pans in discrete jumps rather than allowing a continuous pan.